# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop') while using bootstrap 5 modal in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

Error while trying to show bootstrap 5 modal using javascript.

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const modalElement = document.getElementById('editUserModal');
    const modal = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalElement);
    modal.show();
  };
```

This is the code for modal

```
const EditModal = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="modal fade "
        id="editUserModal"
        aria-hidden="true"
        tabIndex="-1"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">
                Modal 1
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Open second modal
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default EditModal;
```

This is the error[image: error]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')
    at Modal._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:158:39)
    at new Modal (modal.js:69:27)
    at Modal.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:65:41)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:364:22)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (event-handler.js:118:19)
```

I don't want to rely on the react-bootstrap library for this. There was another similar question for the same problem, but it doesn't have a fix either.

Edit: I am attaching the parent components that holds EditModal

```
import ProfileCard from '../../components/profileCard/ProfileCard';
import EditModal from '../../components/editModal/EditModal';
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

const Home = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const modalElement = document.getElementById('editUserModal');
    const modal = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalElement);
    modal.show();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <a
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        onClick={handleClick}
        role="button"
      >
        Open first modal
      </a>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row mt-5">
          <div className="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <EditModal />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: That is because your selector `document.getElementById('editUserModal')` cannot find the element and therefore is returning undefined. Are you attempting to access the element before it is injected into the document? Where are you invoking `handleClick()`? Is the `EditModal` component being dynamically/conditionally rendered?

Comment: I have added a new edit with my parent component. I am not conditionally rendering the modal. I have just placed it in my html and according to the docs I am using JavaScript to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to explicitly set the backdrop:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const modalElement = document.getElementById('editUserModal');
const modal = new Modal(modalElement, {backdrop: false, keyboard: true, focus: true});
modal.show();
```

};

Answer (score 5):

since you are showing/hiding modals via a click handler try to remove `data-bs-toggle="modal"`.

Answer (score 2):

in this part of your code

```
<a
    className="btn btn-primary"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    onClick={handleClick}
    role="button"
  >
```

you added `data-bs-toggle`

and also you have this in your `handleClick`

```
const modal = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalElement);
modal.show();
```

**Both of these can not work together**

if you delete `data-bs-toggle="modal"` from your 'a' tag, then the problem will be resolved.

because already you have modal action in your `handleClick` function

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all libraries are loaded before setup your modal. This is my solution :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
//your modal setup
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the new experimental ["data-bs-config" attribute](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#options):

```
<div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" data-bs-config={backdrop:true}>
```

I think there is a "small" bug in Bootstrap-5.2 and an exception arises if it is not used/defined (I think it should be optional)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering the same exact error as is depicted in this post.

The button that opens the modal is on the first line.

The modal begins on the line after the the close table element.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { variables } from './Variables.js';

export class Department extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            departments: [],
            modalTitle: "",
            DepartmentName: "",
            DepartmentId: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL + 'department')
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then( data => {
            this.setState({departments:data})
        })
    }

    changeDepartmentName = (e) =>{
        this.setState({DepartmentName:e.target.value})
    }

    //clicks
    addClick() {
        this.setState({
            modalTitle: "Add Department",
            departmentId: 0,
            DepartmentName: ""
        })
        console.log()
    }

    editClick(dep) {
        this.setState({
            modalTitle: "Edit Department",
            departmentId: dep.departmentId,
            DepartmentName: dep.DepartmentName
        })
    }

    render(){
        const {
            departments,
            modalTitle,
            DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName
        } = this.state
        return (
        <Fragment>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="exampleModal" onClick={() => this.addClick()}>Add Department</button>
            <table className='table table-striped'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            DepartmentId
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            DepartmentName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Options
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {departments.map(department => 
                        <tr key={department.DepartmentId}>
                        <td>{department.DepartmentId}</td>
                        <td>{department.DepartmentName}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" className='btn btn-light mr-1'
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="exampleModal"
                            onClick={() => this.editClick(department)}>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168l10-10zM11.207 2.5 13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207 11.207 2.5zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293l6.5-6.5zm-9.761 5.175-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325z" /></svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" className='btn btn-light mr-1'>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" data-bs-backdrop="static">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">{modalTitle}</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">Department Name</span>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" value={DepartmentName} onChange={this.changeDepartmentName}></input>
                            </div>
                            {DepartmentId == 0 ? <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start">Create</button> : null}
                            {DepartmentId != 0 ? <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start">Update</button> : null}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to fix this by entering a 'hashtag' before the reference to the modal within the html/react.

Answer (score 1):

If you conditionally render the modal, just remove the condition, it worked for me.
The code snippet with problem, suppose setIsModalOpen becomes true after some button click

```
function Details(){
 const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
 
 return(
   isModalOpen ? <div
    className="modal fade"> //Contents </div>: null
 )}
```

The problem resolved when I removed the isModalOpen condition

```
function Details(){
     const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
     
     return(
      <div
        className="modal fade"> //Contents </div>
     )}
```

The reason could be that all libraries for modal may not be loaded properly

Answer (score 1):

**If you have, like I do, two different buttons to toggle the modal :**

I was facing this same error until I changed the `data-bs-toggle` attribute on one of these two buttons. They apparently need to be different.

`data-bs-target` has the same value on two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The below solved my case.

> Rather than initialize the modal upon mounting, I initialize it on demand.
> https://github.com/orgs/twbs/discussions/37304

Comment: and the null check avoids the error.

` if(modalElement != null) `